# Error: while migrating Event: invalid address (arg="benificiaryAddress", coderType="address", value=undefined)

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

```
let Event = artifacts.require("./Event.sol");

const field= {
    nameOfEvent : "Music",
    ticketCount : 100,
    ticketCharge :10000,
    durationInMinute :1200
  }
module.exports =async function(deployer,accounts){
    await deployer.deploy(Event,field.nameOfEvent,field.ticketCount,field.ticketCharge,field.durationInMinute,accounts[1]);
}
```

My Contract Event is expecting an address at deployment time and I am using ganache.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what contract `Event` constructor looks like???

Answer (score 1):

This is because `accounts[1]` is undefined, since you don't have a 2nd account. This is likely because of your truffle config. Do you mean to use `accounts[0]`?